# How to fix the web page slow down issue in datatables?

Tags: jquery, performance, datatable, datatables

I am set of data's in datatables. when i run the page it toggles the your web page slow down your browser. if i disable the datatable script means page loads fine. how to resolve this issue.

```
   $('#example').DataTable({
    "paging": true,
    "lengthChange": true,
    "searching": true,
    "ordering": true,
    "info": true,
    "autoWidth": true,

  });
```

Comment: How many records are there in your table?

Comment: there are 5000+ records.

Answer (score 0):

You can try server-side processing for loading of datatables with huge records. 
[see here](https://datatables.net/examples/server_side/simple.html)